# Is ionized air ferromagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, air

We know that ionized air is a good electrical conductor, but is it ferromagnetic?
Can it be magnetized?

Comment: Maybe some more context could help in answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Air contains magnetic molecules, namely $O_2 $. Therefore it is paramagnetic. The density of air is too low for it to become ferromagnetic, even if extra  ions are formed with magnetic moments. Solid oxygen can have antiferromagnetic properties. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen

Comment: That's right, but the question is specifically for ionized air, e.g one that has its particles accelerated through the effect of high voltage.